# wp_schedule_event - function won't execute

Tags: wp-cron

I use wp_schedule_event to have the function updatePostCounts() executed every hour. I also use the plugin "WP Crontrol" which shows me that the hook (opbs_update_counts) is there and is run every hour. But when the time is due nothing happens - updatePostCounts() isn't executed. Here's the code.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->addActions();
    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array($this, 'deactivation'));
}
public function deactivation()
{
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('opbs_update_counts');
}


public function addActions()
{

      if( !wp_next_scheduled('opbs_update_counts') )
    {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'opbs_update_counts');
    }
    add_action('opbs_update_counts', array('cronTaskUpdateCounts'));

    add_action('init', array($this, 'action_init'));

        add_action('template_redirect', array($this, 'action_template_redirect'));

}

    public function cronTaskUpdateCounts()
{
     $this->updatePostsCounts();
}
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action('opbs_update_counts', array('cronTaskUpdateCounts'));
```

should be

```
add_action( 'opbs_update_counts', array( $this, 'cronTaskUpdateCounts' ) );
```